# How to send push notification using php in windows phone?

Tags: php, c#-4.0, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

Hi I need to send toast push notification from my windows phone app using PHP. I have used some codes but I can't send push notification.

My code is given below:

```
        private void Click_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        string url = "http://www.best.com/Best_Windows/Login.php";

        Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "sUsername", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.txtEmailaddress.Text));
        postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "sPassword", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.txtPassword.Password.ToString()));

        WebClient client = default(WebClient);
        client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();

        client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
        client.UploadProgressChanged += client_UploadProgressChanged;

        client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());

        prog = new ProgressIndicator();
        prog.IsIndeterminate = true;
        prog.IsVisible = true;
        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, prog);

    }


    private void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == false & e.Error == null)
        {
            prog.IsVisible = false;

            string[] result = e.Result.ToString().Split('|');
            string strStatus = result[0].ToString();
            strcustomer_id_k = result[1].ToString();
            string strError = result[2].ToString();

            if (strStatus == "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(strError);
                LoginPage.strcustomer_id_k = null;
            }
            else
            {
                save_pendingmessage();
            }     




       public void save_pendingmessage()
       { 

         HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for toast events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());

        }            

        string url = "http://www.best.com/Best_Windows/send_message.php";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);


        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "customer_id", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strcustomer_id_k));
        postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "device_uri", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));
        WebClient client = default(WebClient);
        client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();

        client.UploadStringCompleted += client_SaveStringCompleted;

        client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());

        prog = new ProgressIndicator();
        prog.IsVisible = true;
       // prog.Text = "Loading....";
    }
    private void client_SaveStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Cancelled == false && e.Error == null)
        {
            string[] result = e.Result.ToString().Split('|');
            //*** Check Status
            if (result[0].ToString() == "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result[0].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result[0].ToString());
               // NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            prog.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

My php codes given below

**send_message.php**

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","dbname");
 if (isset($_POST["customer_id"]) && isset($_POST["device_uri"])) 
 {
  $notif_url = $_POST["device_uri"];
  $customer_id =  $_POST["customer_id"];

  $getregid = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pim_offerstatus where customer_id='6' and device_uri = 'fghfhghfghfgh' ");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($getregid) > 0) 
  {
   $query = mysqli_query($con,"select count(offer) as count from pim_offerstatus where         customer_id='6' and offer!=''");
   $count = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   $msg = $count['count'];
   $message = array("offer" => $msg." "."The offers received");
   include_once './windowspush.php';
   $windows_push = new WindowsPhonePushNotification($notif_url);
   $res = $windows_push->push($target,$message,$notif_url);

   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "gum registration id is successfully updated";
    // echoing JSON response
  echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
  else 
 {
  required field is missing
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

  echoing JSON response
  echo json_encode($response);
 }
 ?>
```

**windowsphone.php**

```
<?php 
 final class WindowsPhonePushDelay
 {

  const Immediate=0;

  private function __construct(){}
}

class WindowsPhonePushNotification
{
  private $notif_url = '';

  function WindowsPhonePushNotification($notif_url)
  {
    $this->notif_url = $notif_url;
  }
  public function push($target,$message_id,$message1,$notif_url)
  {

  // Create the toast message
  $toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
               "<wp:Toast>" .
                    "<wp:Text1>" . "SendToast" . "</wp:Text1>" .
                    "<wp:Text2>" . $message1 . "</wp:Text2>" .
                    ""<wp:Param>/BestDeal.xaml?=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" .
                    "</wp:Toast> " .
            "</wp:Notification>";

   // Create request to send
   $r = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL,$notif_url);
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

  // add headers
   $httpHeaders=array('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast',
                'Accept: application/*', 'X-NotificationClass: 2','Content-Length:'.strlen($toastMessage));
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeaders);

// add message
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toastMessage);

// execute request
$output = curl_exec($r);
curl_close($r);

 }
}

?>
```

Hi this is my code, I need when the customer log in successfully while send receive push notification in my app. Can you tell me why I am facing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Where in your Windows Phone app do you register the push notification channel?

Comment: Hi i was updated my question, actually when the customer sign up in my app while add push uri and stored database.

Comment: Do you know what's failing about your sending of toast notifications? Is your event handler being called? Is your webserver logging any errors? Have you tried using the sample push server to fake it to isolate if it's the pushing, or the listening that's not working?

Comment: Thats every thing working fine,i didn't get any error. but i didn't get push notification

Comment: I know this is an old question by now, and you may have fixed the issue but in _send_message.php_ you have the line `include_once './windowspush.php';` but your other file is called _windowsphone.php._